# Does the source of force undergo same acceleration?

Tags: forces

When an object applies a force on another, does both have same accelerarion ?

Comment: This is a simple question that can be answered by googling.

Comment: In the same spirit as @QuIcKmAtHs: This is a simple question that can be answered by thinking about every day life. When you push a book on a table do you go flying backwards? When you accelerate your car does the rotation of the Earth change drastically too?

Answer (score 1):

Okay,So I think you must be acquainted with Newton's 3rd law which says **$$F_{AB}=-F_{BA}$$**

It means the sum of internal forces of system is zero.It means the source which is applying force on any object is also acted by an equal magnitude of force but in opposite direction which confirms that source also gets accelerated but the magnitude of acceleration may or may not be the same because it depends on mass of the source as well as the other object.

So mathematically, **$$a_{A}=\frac{-m_{B}a_{B}}{m_{A}}$$**

Comment: Yes but not by the same amount as the mass may differ.

Comment: @badjohn see the edited version.

Comment: It's better now. Might be good to mention $F = ma$ to quantify the extent of the difference.

Comment: @badjohn see the edited version again.

Comment: It's good now.  I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes and No.

Newton's third law states that "For every action, there is an equal and opposite reaction".

That is, when 2 objects $a$ and $b$ exert a force on one another, the force is the *same in magnitude*, but *opposite in direction*.  While the force is the same, the acceleration can only be the same if both are of equal masses, since $F=ma$.  However, if the masses are different, then acceleration will also be different.